# Supervisor FATAL Exited too quickly (process log may have details)

Tags: laravel-5, supervisord

I am using supervisor in laravel some time my supervisor work fine and some time got error.
**FATAL Exited too quickly (process log may have details).**

This is my supervisor file.

```
[program:laravel-worker-mail]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/new-project/artisan queue:work mongodb --sleep=10 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/new-project//storage/logs/worker.log
```

Please suggest me if anybody have good idea about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved the problem myself by searching and applying a number of methods, I found my solution by adding `--daemon` in command
updated code below

```
[program:laravel-worker-mail]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/new-project/artisan queue:work mongodb --sleep=10 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/new-project/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Comment: is not --daemon has been deprecated in laravel 5.4..?

Comment: Yep, `--daemon` is deprecated nowadays so it won't have any effect.

Answer (score 51):

In my case, the supervisor was exiting very fast because it was finishing before the startsecs and since startsecs wasn't defined, it uses the default which is 1.

Setting `startsecs=0` fixed my issue.

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you!

Comment: this did for me too

Comment: I'm glad it help. An upvote will help others too.

Comment: where do u run this?

Comment: @ichimaru, in your supervisor conf file, typically found in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/YourSupervisor.conf` on Ubuntu

Comment: Great tip! Actually worked when I was stumped!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone still having the same issue despite following the accepted answer. It turned out that I was referencing the wrong queue method "sqs" instead of the one I was using which was "database".

> command=php /var/www/html/new-project/artisan queue:work **database** --sleep=10 --tries=3 --daemon

```
[program:laravel-worker-mail]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/new-project/artisan queue:work database --sleep=10 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/new-project/storage/logs/worker.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got this message when trying to run `php artisan horizon` inside a directory that didn't actually have `artisan` available to run.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a bit silly posting this, but I ran into this issue when cloning a server for a new website - and the supervisor conf file was pointing the command to the wrong directory because the new website was hosted in a different location.

So using the example my /etc/supervisor/conf.d/laravel-worker.conf needed to be changed from something like this:

```
[program:laravel-worker-mail]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/new-project/artisan queue:work database --sleep=10 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/new-project/storage/logs/worker.log
```

To this:

```
[program:laravel-worker-mail]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/new-project-2/artisan queue:work database --sleep=10 --tries=3 --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/new-project-2/storage/logs/worker.log
```